What is the unique Ramsey graph in $\mathcal{R}(4,5,20, e=100)$?
According to Angeltveit+McKay, there is a unique graph (up to isomorphism) on 20 vertices with 100 edges that contains no $K_4$ or independent set of size 5 (that is, it is in $\mathcal{R}(4,5,20,e=100)$).
I'd like some presentation of the graph, if anyone knows it or can build it easily.
Am I missing something obvious?

I assume that "according to Angeltveit+McKay" refers to this paper, where the $n=20$ row of Table 1 says that the maximum number of edges in an $\mathcal R(4,5,20)$ graph is $100$ and that there is $1$ such graph.

Yes, that is the paper I was looking at.

@Misha, many thanks for pointing out the error in my rather naive approach. Hope this one is a bit better...
@Craig, why would you think you that you 'miss something obvious'?
These graphs can be quite complicated.
Example: I could just find the unique $R(4,5,v=15,e=60)$ graph and that was a bit of a journey with a lot of third party help

could find the complement $R(5,4,v=15,e=45)$ in the house of graphs https://houseofgraphs.org/search
had it imported to Mathematica to find the graph itself g=GraphComplement[ImportString["N{eCIhJSaWEfIuKqDeG","Graph6"]];

It is

a mid-level symmetry graph (order of graph automorphism group is 24)
pg = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{4,5},{6,7},{8,9},{10,11},{12,13},{14,15}}], Cycles[{{2,3},{6,7},{8,14},{9,15},{10,12},{11,13}}], Cycles[{{2,6,3,7},{8,12,14,10},{9,11,15,13}}], Cycles[{{1,4},{2,8},{3,14},{6,10},{7,12},{11,13}}]}]

regular (degree 8) - though not all extreme R(4,5) graphs are

it has no 4 cliques; only 36 3-cliques with 3 vertices (1, 4 and 5) appearing in 8 3-cliques, all other 12 vertices in 10 3-cliques

no independent sets of 5

the following embedding seems to show what is going on Graph[EdgeList[g],GraphLayout->"SpringElectricalEmbedding", VertexLabels->Automatic, ImageSize->Large]



I guess, I suggest to contact the authors of the paper for the $R(4,5,v=20,e=100)$ case and share the results here...
I had quite some fun getting this far.
